# Will the Windows Bootloader create events?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, bootloader

Will the Windows bootloader add to the event log? So if I boot up Ubuntu, will it show in event viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the event log is part of the Windows OS.  Since the bootloader is loaded before the OS it is not able to write to the event log, although it may have its own log file.  Running Ubuntu will not be logged to the Windows Event Log.

Comment: So does it have it's own log file?

Comment: Yes, logging can be enabled in the bootloader, but it is typically disabled unless you've enabled it.  See the [bcdedit help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202.aspx).  When enabled the log file is: `%WINDIR%\Ntbtlog.txt`